# Behaviour of sizeof with string

Tags: c, string, sizeof

```
‪#‎include‬ <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",sizeof("S\065AB"));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof("S65AB"));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof("S\065\0AB"));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof("S\06\05\0AB"));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof("S6\05AB"));
    printf("%d\n",sizeof("\0S65AB"));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
5
6
6
7
6
7
```

http://ideone.com/kw23IV

Can anyone explain this behaviour with character strings?

Using GCC on Debian 7.4

Comment: You're asking why it isn't stopping at `\0`? Simply because it's reporting the size of the constant which is stored in memory. Sizeof doesn't care that it's a string, null-capped or not. It just sees a statically sized array of characters.

Comment: `sizeof` return a value of type `size_t`; you pass that value to `printf()` specifier `"%d"` which expects an `int`. `size_t` and `int` need not have the same representation: you may get strange results printed. I suggest you use C99's `"%zu"` specifier or cast the value return from `sizeof`: `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof "hello");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of a string literal is the number of characters in it including the trailing null byte that is added.   If there embedded nulls in the string, they are immaterial; they get counted. It is unrelated to `strlen()` except that if the literal includes no embedded nulls, `strlen(s) == sizeof(s) - 1`.

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof("S\065AB"));      // 5: '\065' is a single character
printf("%zu\n", sizeof("S65AB"));        // 6
printf("%zu\n", sizeof("S\065\0AB"));    // 6: '\065' is a single character
printf("%zu\n", sizeof("S\06\05\0AB"));  // 7: '\06' and '\05' are single chars
printf("%zu\n", sizeof("S6\05AB"));      // 6: '\05' is a single character
printf("%zu\n", sizeof("\0S65AB"));      // 7
```

Note that `'\377'` is a valid octal constant, equivalent to `'\xFF'` or 255.  You can use them in strings, too.  The value `'\0'` is only a special case of a more general octal constant.

Note that `sizeof()` evaluates to a value of type `size_t`, and the correct formatting type qualifier in C99 and C11 for `size_t` is `z`, and since it is unsigned, `u` is more appropriate than `d`, hence the `"%zu\n"` format that I used.

Answer (score 2):

A literal character string is an array of exactly the size needed to hold all the characters and an extra terminating zero-byte.

So, `"hello"` has type `char[6]` and `sizeof` yields 6.