# trying to append new text to an existing file using fwrite() with mode "a+" but get weird string written

Tags: c++, fwrite

I am writing a program that is to insert texts to a file every time when it is called. I don't want to rewrite the entire file, and I want the new text could be inserted to a new line. Here is my test code:

```
void writeFile()
{
    FILE *pFile;
    char* data = "hahaha";
    int data_size = 7;
    int count = 1;
    pFile = fopen("textfile.bin","a+");
    if (pFile!=NULL)
    {
        fwrite (data, data_size, count, pFile);
        fclose (pFile);
    }
}
```

At the first time it got called, everything worked fine. A new file was created and the data was successfully written. But when I called it again and expected that a new data to be inserted, I got weird strings in the file, something like:慨慨慨栀桡桡a.

I am not really familiar with C++ I/O functions. Can someone tell me what I did wrong? Also, any suggestion for appending text to the next line?

Comment: `textfile.bin` not invalid, but looks weird name...

Comment: You say that you are "not really familiar with C++ I/O functions". You'll be surprised to learn that there are no C++ I/O functions in the code that you posted. This is not C++. This is C.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/WorSkgNWXT7lrwVy). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you want lines in the file, you'll need to put them there, because `fwrite()` won't put it there unless it is in the data.  You have written a null byte to the file (because you used `data_size = 7`), which means the file is not really a text file (text files don't contain null bytes).  What happens next depends on the code set you're using.  How did you inspect the strings in the file?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is a valid C++ code and The C++ standard ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) 17.2 says "The C ++ standard library also makes available the facilities of the C standard library, suitably adjusted to
ensure static type safety."

Comment: Wasn't this a Notepad bug? Try going to File->Open, and make sure to select UTF-8 or ASCII encoding.

Comment: I did not say anything about "valid C++ code".

Comment: It's not a bug and it's not the Notepad's code. It's a Windows API function that auto-detects the file encoding. Read more: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running into a code set issue, and the program you're using to look at the file you write expects to find UTF-16 data in the file.

I base this on an analysis of the string you quote:

```
慨慨慨栀桡桡a
```

When that (UTF-8) data is converted to Unicode values, I get:

```
0xE6 0x85 0xA8 = U+6168
0xE6 0x85 0xA8 = U+6168
0xE6 0x85 0xA8 = U+6168
0xE6 0xA0 0x80 = U+6800
0xE6 0xA1 0xA1 = U+6861
0xE6 0xA1 0xA1 = U+6861
0x61 = U+0061
0x0A = U+000A
```

The Unicode values U+6168 is represented in little-endian as bytes 0x68 0x61, and the ASCII code for `h` is 104 (0x68) and for `a` is 97 (0x61).  So, the data is probably written correctly, but the interpretation of the data that is written is incorrect.

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927261/trying-to-append-new-text-to-an-existing-file-using-fwrite-with-mode-a-but/36927363#comment61415490_36927261):

> If you want lines in the file, you'll need to put them there (by adding newlines to the data that is written), because `fwrite()` won't output any newlines unless they are in the data it is given to write. You have written a null byte to the file (because you used `data_size = 7`), which means the file is not really a text file (text files don't contain null bytes). What happens next depends on the code set you're using.

The trailing single-byte codes in the output appear because the second null byte isn't visible in what's pasted on this page, and the trailing U+000A was added by the `echo` in the command line I used for the analysis (where `utf8-unicode` is a program I wrote):

```
 echo "慨慨慨栀桡桡a" | utf8-unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
char* data = "hahaha\0";
pFile = fopen("textfile.bin","a+");
if (pFile!=NULL)
{
    fwrite (data, sizeof(char), strlen(data), pFile);
    fclose (pFile);
}
```

Comment: Why is the `\0` in the string necessary, or a benefit?  The compiler adds a null byte after the third `a` anyway; there's no need for yours to be added too.

Comment: either write 7 bytes with the '\0' or 6 without it

Comment: Since `strlen()` stops counting at the first null byte, it makes no difference whether you put the explicit `\0` into the string (before the compiler-supplied one) or simply use the one supplied by the compiler. Either way, the value returned from `strlen()` in this context will be 6. If you're thinking of `sizeof()` — `sizeof("hahaha")` is 7; `sizeof("hahaha\0") is 8, but `sizeof(data)` is 4 (32-bit) or 8 (64-bit) — then this example has ramifications that don't really fit in a comment (see [Behaviour of `sizeof` with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749424/g/22749454#22749454)).